# Hibernate QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

I am getting the exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: dayofweek near line 1, column 155
```

Below is my function to query the table

```
    Session session = getSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select count(tex.task.id)" + " from " + TestExecution.class.getName() + " tex where tex.userId=:userId and " +
            "tex.executedAt >= curdate()- interval dayofweek(curdate())+6 day and tex.executedAt < curdate() - interval dayofweek(curdate())-1 DAY");
    query.setParameter("userId", userId);
    return (long) query.uniqueResult();
```

Please help me..

Comment: what is exactly the meaning of this "dayofweek", shouldn't there be some sign between "interval" and "dayofweek" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `createSQLQuery` method instead:

```
Session session = getSession();
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select count(tex.task.id)" + " from " + TestExecution.class.getName() + " tex where tex.userId=:userId and " +
        "tex.executedAt >= curdate()- interval dayofweek(curdate())+6 day and tex.executedAt < curdate() - interval dayofweek(curdate())-1 DAY");
query.setParameter("userId", userId);
return (long) query.uniqueResult();
```